# Displaying text using onMouseover JavaScript/HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I have a task that calls for an image of a famous person and the goal here is that once the user moves the mouse onto the image, a text displaying a quote made by that person will be visible. Once the user moves off the image, the text will disappear. This sounds relatively simple and I know this can be done using CSS however I wish to broaden my HTML skills and will ignore CSS for now and focus on HTML and JS. Now I know that the onMouseover is the key event handler for this, however I feel as if my code has errors that I'm not aware. Everything is enclosed within the script tags. Thanks.

```
<img src="julius_caesar.jpg" id="jCaes" onMouseover="displayQuote();">
function displayQuote() {
document.getElementById("jCaes").value = "I came, I saw, I conquered";
}
```

Comment: just add the text in the `title` attribute of the `img`

Comment: you don't need onMouseover event for that, just add title attribute to your image tag like <img src="…" title="Text you want to show" .. />

Answer (score 3):

You need a title attribute to display text on mouse hover.

```
<img src="julius_caesar.jpg" id="jCaes" title="your text"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Solution One:** You can add a title attribute to your HTML tag:

```
<img src="julius_caesar.jpg" id="jCaes" title="your text" />
```

**Solution Two:** You could use css for this too (if you want to style the quote that is displayed):

```
div.quote {
    display: none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:30px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
}

img#jCaes:hover + div.quote {
    display: block;
}
```

**Solution Three:** There's really no need to use JavaScript for this; however, here's a JS solution as well:

Additional HTML:

```
<div id="popup">Your quote here</div>
```

CSS:

```
#popup {
  display:none;
}
```

JS

```
var e = document.getElementById('jCaes');

e.onmouseover = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'block';
}

e.onmouseout = function() {
  document.getElementById('popup').style.display = 'none';
}
```

**Solution Four:** Here's another solution if you can use jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/9RxLM/

Comment: You just copied Nakul91's answer

Comment: Well that is the most basic solution. I've since given another option as well though.

Answer (score 1):

Like this
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/xg7nog42/1/) ?

```css
body {
    padding:30px;
    font:normal 12px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Hover tooltips */
.field-tip {
    position:relative;
    cursor:help;
}
    .field-tip .tip-content {
        position:absolute;
        top:-22px; /* - top padding */
        right:9999px;
        width:200px;
        margin-right:-220px; /* width + left/right padding */
        padding:10px;
        color:#fff;
        background:#333;
        -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #aaa;
           -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #aaa;
                box-shadow:2px 2px 5px #aaa;
        opacity:0;
        -webkit-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
           -moz-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
            -ms-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
             -o-transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
                transition:opacity 250ms ease-out;
    }
        /* <http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/> */
        .field-tip .tip-content:before {
            content:' '; /* Must have content to display */
            position:absolute;
            top:50%;
            left:-16px; /* 2 x border width */
            width:0;
            height:0;
            margin-top:-8px; /* - border width */
            border:8px solid transparent;
            border-right-color:#333;
        }
        .field-tip:hover .tip-content {
            right:-20px;
            opacity:1;
        }
```

```html
<span class="field-tip">
    <img src = "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/41bd91a4e61ab446e69a72e54dade869?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <span class="tip-content">This Is my Quote.</span>
</span>
```

If this what you want then Bootstrap Tooltip also help you.

See [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vSTLU/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Tag img not have attribute "value"

```
<script>
    function displayQuote() {
        document.getElementById("jCaes").textContent = "I came, I saw, I conquered";
    }
</script>

<img src="http://www.tivix.com/uploads/blog_pics/Android-logo.png"  onMouseover="displayQuote();" height="150" width="150">
<p id="jCaes"></p>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, you guys are great! Practice makes perfect!